# Signxml verifying failing

Tags: python, digital-signature, xml-signature

I have scenario where I have to sign some data and send it to client through TCP socket.

So at server I sign it using xmlsign and send it as a string

```
#in server
signed_xml_obj = XMLSigner().sign(root, key=PRIVATEKEY)
xml_str = ElementTree.tostring(signed_xml_obj)
#sendtoclient(xml_str)
```

Than in client a create a ElementTree.Element from string and try to verify it but it fails

```
#somewhere in client
signed_xml_obj = ElementTree.fromstring(signiautreString)
XMLVerifier().verify(signed_xml_obj, x509_cert=cer)
```

Traceback

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/eltioni/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/signxml/__init__.py", line 729, in verify
    verify(signing_cert, raw_signature, signed_info_c14n, signature_digest_method)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 2928, in verify
    _raise_current_error()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 54, in exception_from_error_queue
    raise exception_type(errors)
OpenSSL.crypto.Error: [('rsa routines', 'int_rsa_verify', 'bad signature')]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sig.py", line 15, in <module>
    XMLVerifier().verify(xml2, x509_cert=cert)
  File "/eltioni/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/signxml/__init__.py", line 735, in verify
    raise InvalidSignature("Signature verification failed: {}".format(reason))
signxml.exceptions.InvalidSignature: Signature verification failed: bad signature
```

Also something I noticed is that when I print signed_xml_obj in the server i get

```
print(signed_xml_obj)
#<Element Student at 0x7ff94085f188>
```

And when I print signed_xml_obj in the client I get 'Student' (with quotes)

```
print(signed_xml_obj)
#<Element 'Student' at 0x7ff94085f188>
```

Comment: Provide the traceback